# Script doesn't seem to work correctly when compiled to android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the problem in my game; when the player collides with an obstacle, the mesh of the player is checked against the obstacle's tag, if they match the player's mesh is changed. It works in the editor but not work after building to apk. As an aside, can I abbreviate the compare tag?

Collision

```
 public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(other.gameObject.tag, "^(Cube|Sphere|Prism|[A-Z]) Instance$") == (other.CompareTag(playerMesh.mesh.name)))       //If player collides with an obstacle
    {
        //If the collided gameObject has the same mesh as the player

        for (int i = 0; i < meshes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (meshes[i].name == other.transform.tag[0].ToString())
            {
                Camera.main.GetComponent<Animation>().Play();
                other.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
                StartCoroutine(Hit());
                playerMesh.mesh = meshes[i + 1];       //Changes the player's mesh
                indtX++;
                Alphabetconfig();
            }
        }
        print("sarua");
        GameObject tempCollisionParticle = Instantiate(collisionParticle, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);     //Instantiates a collisionParticle to the player's position
        tempCollisionParticle.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = playerRen.material.color;       //Sets its color identical to the player's color
        Destroy(tempCollisionParticle, 1.2f);       //Destroys it after x seconds
    }
    else if (other.CompareTag("Token"))
    {
        gameIsOver = false;
        FindObjectOfType<ScoreManager>().IncrementToken();
        //token sound
        Destroy(Instantiate(tokenParticle, transform.position, Quaternion.identity), 1.2f);
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }

    else if (other.CompareTag("Health"))
    {
        gameIsOver = false;
        //healthsound
        stats.playerCurrenthealth++;
        if (stats.playerCurrenthealth > stats.playerMaxhealth)
        {
            stats.playerCurrenthealth = stats.playerMaxhealth;
        }
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
    else if (other.CompareTag("Book"))
    {
        gameIsOver = false;
        //healthsound
        StartCoroutine(ImmuneTime());
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
    else if (other.CompareTag("Wrench"))
    {
        gameIsOver = false;
        //HealthSound
        stats.playerCurrenthealth++;
        if (stats.playerCurrenthealth > stats.playerMaxhealth)
        {
            stats.playerCurrenthealth = stats.playerMaxhealth;
        }
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
    else if (other.CompareTag("Pen"))
    {
        gameIsOver = false;
        //healthsound
        StartCoroutine(FlyTime());
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }

    else        //If the tags are different
    {
        stats.Immune = false;
        gameIsOver = false;
        stats.Damage(1);
        if (stats.playerCurrenthealth < 0)
        {
            gameIsOver = true;      //Game is over
                                    //Plays 'deathSound'
            trailRen.enabled = playerRen.enabled = false;
            GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndPanelActivation();
        }

        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();
        //FindObjectOfType<ScoreManager>().IncrementScore();      //Increments score
        //Plays Colides

    }

}
```

I know the problem but I don't know how to fix it, it's like when I build to android the script reverse function, `if` become `else` and `else` become `if. I don't know what happens, it is from editor or maybe my script?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you use `meshes[i].name == other.transform.tag[i].ToString()` when you already knew about `CompareTag()`? Why did you do `CompareTag(GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.name)` when you already saved the results of `GetComponent<MeshFilter>` to a field (`playerMesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();`)? `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>()` is the same as `Camera.main`. And why do you do that *and* `FindObjectOfType<Camera>()`?

Comment: `using System.Text.RegularExpressions; ... if( Regex.Matches(other.gameObject.tag, "^(Cube|Sphere|Prism|[A-Z]) Instance$") )`

Comment: @Draco18s why I use `meshes[i].name == other.transform.tag[i].ToString() `because if not use that the` meshes.name` will move to the end of a length of meshes, Why did you do `CompareTag(GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.name)` this is for when the player collides with obstacle with the same name on it so the mesh will adjust with the last hit with an obstacle like if the player collides with `a` then the mesh will be `a`

Comment: @Ruzihm when i use this if( Regex.Matches(other.gameObject.tag, "^(Cube|Sphere|Prism|[A-Z]) Instance$") ) show this error Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' to 'bool' Assembly-CSharp –

Comment: Ah, it should be `Regex.IsMatch`: `using System.Text.RegularExpressions; ... if( Regex.IsMatch(other.gameObject.tag, "^(Cube|Sphere|Prism|[A-Z]) Instance$") )`

Comment: What I meant was "use `CompareTag(meshes[i].name)` instead."